Why is the temperature of electron-proton recombination obtained from Saha equation so small?
I read a blog about the temperature of the Universe at recombination phase.
The ionization potential of a hydrogen atom is $13.6\, eV$, throw it into the thermal energy equation $E=\frac{3}{2}kT$, will yield a temperature about $105000 \, K$, which is incorrect.
By manipulating the Saha equation, we obtain $$\frac{x_e^2}{(1-x_e)}=\frac{1}{1.6(1+z)^3}(\frac{m_ek_B}{2\pi h^2})^{3/2}T^{3/2}\exp(-\frac{E_1}{k_BT})$$, where $x_e$ is the fraction of free electron.
Solving it numerically, the temperature at which recombination is nearly complete ($x_e \approx 0$) is around $3000 \, K$.
This is way smaller than $105000\, K$. Not only that, but if we slightly increase the temperature, say $4000 \, K$, the free electron abundance surges to about 60%.
Mathematically, I think it's because the exponential term in the Saha equation dominates and make the result very sensitive to even small changes.
However, I am having trouble to physically interpret this phenomenon, why is $x_e$, the fraction of free electron, can be so high at relative low temperatures such as $4000\, K$, which is far below $105000 \, K$.
